# Access the month of a date using laravel/postgres

Tags: postgresql, date, laravel, eloquent

I'm making my first laravel project, using postgres, and I'd like to be able to access all the people with a birthday this month (my people table has a birthdate field that's a date). I've looked around and I can't figure out the right syntax for accessing the month and comparing with the current month.

I've tried a few ways in my controller:

1) here the arrow operator is unexpected for birthdate->month:

```
  public function get_birthday_people()
{
    $this_month = \Carbon\Carbon::now()->month;

    $birthday_people = Person::all()
        ->Where('birthdate'->month, $this_month)
        ->Where('active', true)
        ->get();

    return $birthday_people;
```

}

2) here I get Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::whereMonth():

```
public function get_birthday_people()
{
    $birthday_people = Person::all()
        ->whereMonth('birthdate', '=', Carbon::now()->month)
        ->Where('active', true)
        ->get();
    return $birthday_people;
}
```

What's the right way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try somethind like this

```
 $birthday_people = Person::all()
    ->where("date_trunc('month', birthdate)", "=", Carbon::now()->month)
    ->where("active", true)->get();
```

OR

```
$birthday_people = Person::all()
        ->where("extract(MONTH from birthdate)", "=", Carbon::now()->month)
        ->where("active", true)->get();
```

Extract is equal to MySQL MOTNH() or YEAR() and etc.
[Ref](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-EXTRACT)

Comment: Thank you!  Yes, reading those postgres datetime functions now, extract sounds like what I want, and now it's valid syntax- thank you!

Unfortunately it's not matching yet- I get no results, even though there are plenty of people with november birthdays- so I'll continue investigating but this is a big help!

Comment: try just to add a dummy record, just to check.

Comment: Yeah this is definitely the right thing to use- it's working when I query my database, but it's not working from my laravel controller.  I'll spin off a new question so this doesn't get too messy: 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33544077/postgres-extract-not-working-in-laravel
Thanks for your help!