# Trying to get month from date in laravel (and postgres extract not working)

Tags: postgresql, laravel, extract

I'm making my first laravel project, using postgres, and I'd like to be able to access all the people with a birthday this month (my people table has a birthdate field that's a date). I can use **extract** to get these records from the database, like so:

```
select * from people 
   where extract (month from birthdate) = 11;
```

But when I try a few different ways in my controller I get 'unknown column' errors:

```
$birthday_people = DB::table('people')
    ->where ("extract(month from birthdate)", "=", "11")
    ->get();
```

(I'll ultimately adjust it to compare with *Carbon::now()->month*, and use the model *Person::all()*, but until I get some results coming through I'm going as simple as possible)

Is there a special way to get the month from a date in laravel?

**Update**: I'm using a scope now in my Person model.  I can get person results to come through when I give it an exact date:

```
public function scopeBirthdays($query)
{
    return $query->where('birthdate', '=', '1947-11-02');
}
```

And I *can* get results back for month if I do it this way, but the catch is it doesn't seem to know it's a collection of People anymore (I can't access person columns when I display it out and I can't chain other scopes):

```
public function scopeBirthdays($query)
{
    return $query->whereRaw('extract(month from birthdate) = ?', ['11'])->get();
}
```

Laravel's query builder offers 'whereMonth'- (seems the most *right*), but it gave me an 'undefined function' error until I put the bool on the end, and now the current error suggests that it's interpretting number of months instead of which one(?):

```
public function scopeBirthdays($query)
{
   return $query->whereMonth('birthdate', '=', Carbon::today()->month, true);
}
```

I get: 
Syntax error: 7 ERROR: syntax error at or near "month"
LINE 1: select * from "people" where 1 month("birthdate") = $1
^ (SQL: select * from "people" where 1 month("birthdate") = 11)

**Final update:** I was able to get results back (that were correctly interpretted as people) by using whereRaw in my scope:

```
public function scopeBirthdays($query)
{
    return $query->whereRaw('extract(month from birthdate) = ?', [Carbon::today()->month])->orderBy ('birthdate', 'asc');
}
```

Thanks, everyone!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

based on previous question try:

```
$birthday_people = DB::table('people')
    ->whereRaw("extract(month from birthdate)", "=", "11")
    ->get();
```

You can set is as relationship

```
public function custom(){
   return $this->hasMany('App\Models\People')->whereRaw("extract(month from birthdate)", "=", "11");
}
```

Comment: Thank you- that does get me results!  The downside is they're not being interpretted as 'people' results (I can't make use of scopes & fields & stuff)- updated description above with what happens

Comment: ooh that looks promising- will try tonight when I get home!  Thank you :)

Comment: Thanks again for your help- that whereRaw let me get results back from a scope in my model like so: 

    public function scopeBirthdays($query)
    {
        return $query->whereRaw('extract(month from birthdate) = ?', [Carbon::today()->month])->orderBy ('birthdate', 'asc');
    }

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this. It will return as an instance of App\People so you will be able to use your eloquent functions still.

```
public function scopeBirthdays($query)
{
    return $query->where('birthdate', 'LIKE', Carbon::today()->year . '-'.Carbon::today()->month.'%');
}
```

I don't have much experience with Carbon, I'm assuming that Carbon::today() will return an object with the year, month, and date.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion!  It didn't like 'like' and gave me an undefined function, but luckily I was able to get there with the 'whereRaw' suggestion above.  So grateful for the stackoverflow universe :)